# Swipe viewControllers on TabBar controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have TabBar Controller with 3 ViewController added on it. Now all tabs switched properly when we click on perticular tab. I want, the same functionality on swiping the TabBar from left to right or righ to left.
So please give me suggestion.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to your `UITabBar`

And handle swipe gestures by setting according to gesture direction

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftToRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftToRightSwipeDidFire)];
    leftToRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addGestureRecognizer:leftToRightGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightToLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightToLeftSwipeDidFire)];
    rightToLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addGestureRecognizer:rightToLeftGesture];
}


- (void)leftToRightSwipeDidFire {
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    NSInteger index = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:tabBar.selectedItem];
    if (index > 0) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index - 1;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
- (void)rightToLeftSwipeDidFire {
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    NSInteger index = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:tabBar.selectedItem];
    if (index < tabBar.items.count - 1) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index + 1;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You right, I forget, that we need to manage UITabBarController instead of tab bar. See updated answer

Comment: i think it is not detecting my gesture

Comment: I think you should check this project: everything is works https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/tabbar.zip

Comment: nope. i have tried this on iphone also still not working

Answer (score 1):

Add 2(One for left and Other for right) swipe gesture to each view controller's view and make IBAction

```
- (IBAction)swipeRightAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {


    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection directions=[(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender direction];
    switch (directions) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
           indexNumberItem--;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            indexNumberItem++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


        if (indexNumberItem<3) {
            indexNumberItem=0;
        }
        if (indexNumberItem>=3) {
            indexNumberItem=2;
        }



    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController= [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexNumberItem];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your child ViewControllers can Inherit from a class that does all the heavy lifting for you.

This is how I have done it

```
class SwipableTabVC : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeLeft))
        left.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(left)

        let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight))
        right.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(right)
    }

    func swipeLeft() {
        let total = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers!.count - 1
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = min(total, tabBarController!.selectedIndex + 1)

    }

    func swipeRight() {
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = max(0, tabBarController!.selectedIndex - 1)
    }
}
```

Now all your viewcontrollers that are part of UITabBarController can inherit from `SwipableTabVC` instead of UIViewController.